# Calculations in class Student

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, calculation

I have created two classes: Person and Student in different modules. Here is my class Person:

```
import datetime


class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, surname, patronymic, birthdate):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.patronymic = patronymic
        self.birthdate = birthdate

    def age(self):#this function calculates age of person
        today = datetime.date.today()
        age = today.year - self.birthdate.year

        if today < datetime.date(today.year, self.birthdate.month, self.birthdate.day):
            age -= 1

        return age
```

Here is my class Student:

```
from ClassPerson import Person


class Student(Person):
    number_of_group = eval(input("\nInput number of group: "))
    summa = 0
    amount_of_students = 0
    overall_age = 0

    def __init__(self, name, surname, patronymic, birthdate, faculty, group, scholarship):
        Person.__init__(self, name, surname, patronymic, birthdate)
        self.faculty = faculty
        self.group = group
        self.scholarship = scholarship
        if Student.number_of_group == self.group:
            Student.summa += self.scholarship
            Student.overall_age += Student.age(self)
            Student.amount_of_students += 1

    @property
        def scholarship(self):
            return self.__scholarship

    @scholarship.setter
    def scholarship(self, new_s):
        if new_s < 1300:
            self.__scholarship = 1300
        elif new_s > 4000:
            self.__scholarship = 4000
        else:
            self.__scholarship = new_s
```

I have one simple problem: I need to calculate for specific group overall sum of scholarships and middle age of students of this group. I do calculations in `def __init__`. But i also had property and setter to change the amount of scholarship due to conditions. So for example we have 3 students:

```
student1 = Student(
    "Joe",
    "Hapfy",
    "Canes",
    datetime.date(1992, 3, 12),
    "Philosophy faculty",
    441,
    4300
)

student2 = Student(
    "Jane",
    "Mers",
    "Rodrigo",
    datetime.date(1998, 4, 29),
    "Historical faculty",
    441,
    2700
)

student3 = Student(
    "Pavlo",
    "Hornov",
    "Andriyovich",
    datetime.date(1997, 7, 22),
    "Mathematics faculty",
    171,
    1300
)
```

I want to change student1 scholarship. For example:

```
student1.scholarship = 1500
print(student1.scholarship)
```

But the changes are not saved, cause i do calculations in `dev __init__`. For example, I input number of group as 441.

```
result = Student.overall_age/Student.amount_of_students
print("Total sum of scholarships: %d" % Student.summa)
```

The sum of scholarships will be 4300+2700, but due to setter 4300 will be changed to 4000 and sum will be 6700. But now my student1 scholarship is 1500 and i want to receive result 1500+2700=4200. How can i do such calculations after changes of scholarship? Should  I use method or something like that instead of calculations in `dev __init__`?

Comment: Do not use `eval` when you mean `int`.

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to ask for input when defining the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property setter needs to update `Student.summa` when necessary.

Since the setter needs to read the old value, we can't use it before we initialize the internal `__scholarship` attribute. So the `__init__()` method needs to assign directly to the internal attribute, rather than using the setter with `self.scholarship`.

```
from ClassPerson import Person


class Student(Person):
    number_of_group = eval(input("\nInput number of group: "))
    summa = 0
    amount_of_students = 0
    overall_age = 0

    def __init__(self, name, surname, patronymic, birthdate, faculty, group, scholarship):
        Person.__init__(self, name, surname, patronymic, birthdate)
        self.faculty = faculty
        self.group = group
        self.__scholarship = scholarship
        if Student.number_of_group == self.group:
            Student.summa += self.scholarship
            Student.overall_age += Student.age(self)
            Student.amount_of_students += 1

    @property
    def scholarship(self):
        return self.__scholarship

    @scholarship.setter
    def scholarship(self, new_s):
        old_s = self.__scholarship
        if new_s < 1300:
            self.__scholarship = 1300
        elif new_s > 4000:
            self.__scholarship = 4000
        else:
            self.__scholarship = new_s

        # Adjust Student.summa by the change in scholarship
        if self.group == Student.number_of_group:
            Student.summa += self.__scholarship - old_s
```

Comment: Thanks! But where i should use variable old_s?

Comment: You use it where I showed, in the calculation of `Student.summa`.

Comment: This part of code shows me unresolved reference to class Student and then i receive errors during calculations: `old_s = self.__scholarship`

Comment: Sounds like you got the indentation wrong. That line has to be inside the method, as shown in my answer.

Comment: I'm using PyCharm and I copied your part of code, and still I received errors

Comment: You have incorrect indentation after `@property`. `def scholarship(self)` needs to be at the same indentation level as `@property`.

Comment: Here it is code from IDE: `@property
    def scholarship(self):
        return self.__scholarship

    @scholarship.setter
    def scholarship(self, new_s):
        old_s = self.__scholarship
        if new_s < 1300:
            self.__scholarship = 1300
        elif new_s > 4000:
            self.__scholarship = 4000
        else:
            self.__scholarship = new_s
        if self.group == Student.number_of_group:
            Student.summa += self.__scholarship - old_s` It's at the same indentation level.

Comment: Here is the warning: Unresolved attribute reference '__scholarship' for class 'Student'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243668/discussion-between-vorrven-and-barmar).

Comment: Can you read my another problem in chat? How can i fix this one?